# Swift for TensorFlow `error: Couldn't lookup symbols: type metadata accessor for TensorFlow.Tensor`

Tags: swift, xcode, tensorflow, swift-playground, swift-for-tensorflow

The following lines -

```
import TensorFlow
let matrix = Tensor<Float>([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

executed in macOS playground produce error -

```
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  type metadata accessor for TensorFlow.Tensor
  protocol witness table for TensorFlow.Tensor<A> : TensorFlow.TensorArrayProtocol in TensorFlow
  type metadata accessor for TensorFlow.TensorElementLiteral
  protocol witness table for TensorFlow.TensorElementLiteral<A> : TensorFlow.TensorArrayProtocol in TensorFlow
  protocol conformance descriptor for <A where A: TensorFlow.TensorArrayProtocol> Swift.Array<A> : TensorFlow.TensorArrayProtocol in TensorFlow
  protocol witness table for Swift.Float : TensorFlow.TensorFlowScalar in TensorFlow
  _TFE_DeleteOp
  _TFE_NewOp
  _TFE_OpSetAttrInt
  _TFE_OpSetAttrType
  _TF_DeleteStatus
  _TF_NewStatus
  ___tf_tensor_from_scalar
  __swift_tfc_CheckOk
  __swift_tfc_CreateTensorHandleFromC
  __swift_tfc_EagerExecute
  __swift_tfc_GetGlobalEagerContext
  __swift_tfc_OpAddInputFromTensorGroup
  __swift_tfc_OpSetDeviceFromScope
```

Xcode 10.2, Swift for TensorFlow Release 0.2, 2019-03-02

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

P.S. The problem persists also with 0.3, 2019-04-23 toolchain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems to be a known issue -
https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/issues/173